# How do I use an XML layout for an android wear watchface?

Tags: xml, wear-os, watch, ondraw, watchface

I've been researching how to make an android wear watchface with little luck. Youtube does not appear to have very much information on actually designing a watchface.

Is there a way to use an XML layout for the watchface rather than, for example, manually drawing each block through on draw?

Answer (score 3):

It's possible, though there are some extra hoops you need to jump through. I've written up instructions at https://sterlingudell.wordpress.com/2015/05/10/layout-based-watch-faces-for-android-wear/

Comment: Thanks for the reply i checked out the link and setup my watchface service but unfortunately whenever i try launching it on my lg urbane the watchface becomes unresponsive and crashes.

Comment: i found this in my log cat hopefully it helps 01-31 09:49:48.088 2442-2442/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.watchface.knight.watchfacetesting, PID: 2442
                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
                                                     at com.watchface.knight.watchfacetesting.DefaultTestFace$Engine.onDraw(DefaultTestFace.java:316)

Comment: As you know, it's very difficult to tell from one line out of logcat, but I'd guess that your layout isn't inflated. But this crash is just a regular NPE, and your existing Android debugging skills should be applicable.

Comment: This approach works fine, but apparently for text-based views only, `ImageView` and empty layouts aren't working. Any particular reason behind that?

Comment: Not sure about empty layouts, but I definitely have this working with `ImageView`s in other watch faces. Are you doing the `measure` and `layout` calls after all your views are set up?

Comment: I tried your instructions with a custom view and it works really good ... but i don't get touch events on that view ... is it somehow possible to enable touch events on a custom view on a watch face?

Comment: No, you can't get ordinary touch events on a watch face, regardless of whether you use a layout. You need to work within the scope of the `onTapCommand` event: https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/watch-faces/interacting